# Does Elementary OS Freya Support SSD Trim?

Tags: release-freya

Plan to use the latest version of elementary OS Freya 64-bit on a ThinkPad T420 with a Kingdian 60GB SATA III SSD (hey, it was $27, don't laugh) and I have confirmed the SSD supports TRIM under Windows, but is there anything I will need to do to make it work automatically on Linux? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has TRIM support enabled by default, and since elementary OS is based on 14.04, I'd say yes.

To confirm this option, you can try from terminal:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep "TRIM supported"
```